# Degrees of freedom for a paired t-test

Tags: probability, statistics

Mean 1=52.1

SD 1=45.1

Mean 2=27.1

SD 2=26.4

I've been trying to find the degrees of freedom for a paired t-test for the data above and got 33.879 every time, but the answer is supposed to be 21. I even put the data into an online degrees of freedom calculator and still got 33.879. Is there some special way to calculate degrees of freedom for paired t-tests?

Comment: Degree of freedom is independent of Mean and SD

Comment: What is your sample size ?